# Ionic, Firebase - How to do ngFor inside ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

### Background

I am doing an Ionic project. I am creating a restaurant menu application, in which I have an array inside array. The structure is like this:

**Menu

--category[]

----menuContent[]**

firebase tree like so:

```
{
  "menu" : {
    "fhsSuizYVhYfwk3jE6Hs1jJ9mul2" : {
      "-LPgLdhiRWtzGZcT68kB" : {
        "category" : "Chicken",
        "menuContent" : {
          "-LPjfZG88i8oir4qZeUr" : {
            "description" : "Tasty & Spicy",
            "menuName" : "Chicken Spicy",
            "menuPrice" : "15000"
          },
          "-LPjmsYuscg0ceMTMriM" : {
            "description" : "Delicious",
            "menuName" : "Sweet Chicken",
            "menuPrice" : "17000"
          }
        }
      },
      "-LPjoKAm8mQsNK1MAPsu" : {
        "category" : "Beef",
        "menuContent" : {
          "-LPk-5YZQtreZQw1vGyL" : {
            "description" : "Dark, sweet, spicy. Yumm!",
            "menuName" : "Beef Blackpepper",
            "menuPrice" : "20000"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the view of my application:

[image]

Now, I want, under the **Category: Chicken** , I get the list of array under `"menuContent"` under `"category" : "Chicken"`

How do I do that?

### My Code

This is my **menu.html**

```
<button ion-button (click)="addCategory()">Add Category</button>

  <ion-list>

    <ion-list-header *ngFor="let dataCat of menuCatData | async">
      <h2>Category: {{dataCat.payload.val().category}}</h2>
      <button ion-button (click)="addMenu(dataCat)">Add Menu</button>
    </ion-list-header>
  </ion-list>
```

And here is my **menu.ts**

```
export class MenuPage {

      menuCatRef: AngularFireList<MenuCategory>;
      menuCatData: Observable<AngularFireAction<DatabaseSnapshot<MenuCategory>>[]>;

      constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase,
        private actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController,
        public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
      }

      ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(data => {
          if(data && data.email && data.uid){

            this.menuCatRef = this.afDatabase.list<MenuCategory>(`menu/${data.uid}`);
            this.menuCatData = this.menuCatRef.snapshotChanges();

        }});
      }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try adding another *ngFor inside your template like “let data of dataCat” etc.

Comment: Yes I have. I added `<ion-item *ngFor="let dataCatVal of dataCat.menuContent"></ion-item>`. But it still doesn't show up.